# Belkin USB PDA Adapter Driver

Tags: macos, snow-leopard

I'm trying to install "Belkin USB PDA Adapter Driver" and I'm getting message:

You can't open the application Belkin USB PDA Adapter Driver because the Classic environment is longer supported.

What can I do in order to get it to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look for updated drivers.

This is an app written for Mac OS 9, so there's really no way to get it to work with a computer running OS X.

Comment: went to manufacture's website they only have for OS9, and Vista, not even for W7, and I thought I'm going go with "big" brand name like Belkin to make sure everything is "ok"... go figure...